# How many conditions are allowed in an "if" statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a limit to how many conditions (e.g., logical OR conditions) that JavaScript allows me to have in an `if` statement, or can I have as many as I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many as you want

Comment: You can use as many or conditions in an if statement. All will end in a single boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

`If` technically have not limits, but If you want a clean code, I recommend you use switch case.

Know more about how to write better conditionals statements here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/posts/5-tips-to-write-better-conditionals-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to use as many as conditions you want , but if we have so many conditions its always good practice to use SWITCH case to make code clean and efficent.